# Cannot open popup from link

Tags: javascript

Hi guys i have a little problem with calling popup by id from link. It`s working on click but cannot call from url something like exaple.com/#id

```js
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$('a.ajax-post').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    $("a.ajax-post").on("click", function(e) {
        // show popup 
        $(".popup.supernova").addClass("is-show");

        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent Default Behaviour
        var post_id = $(this).attr("id"); //Get Post ID

        // Ajax Call
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            timeout: 8000,
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "theme_post_example",
                id: post_id
            },

            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#ajax-response").html("Loading");
            },

            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var $ajax_response = $(data);
                $("#ajax-response").html($ajax_response);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $("#ajax-response").addClass("show-content");
                }, 100);
                /* $(".popup.supernova").append(script); */
            },

            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(
                    "The following error occured: " + textStatus,
                    errorThrown
                );
            },

            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {},
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="8" class="catalog__item popup-8 ajax-post">
    <span class="catalog__title">Title</span>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="" id="img_8">
</a>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it? and why its not working. im new in js. Thanks in advance

Comment: Very unclear what you even mean by “popup” here. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I mean js popup window

Comment: A native link can open real pop-ups only. As your pop-up is a regular HTML element, which is hidden when "closed", you need a click listener for the link. In the listener you set the pop-up element visible again.

Comment: how i can do it can u show me some example? @Teemu

Comment: It looks like you've already done that. A traditional pop-up is a navigable window with its own document, you can't show and hide elements with an URL. You've either to create a file, which contains the HTML, JS and CSS for the pop-up only, then load that file on pop-up with a link (set `target="_blank"` for the link), or catch ex. the hash from the URL when the page has been parsed, and show the "pop-up" with JS as you've done in your code.

Comment: @Ken A popup is open, if you use following code `window.open()`. I think you meant show a div layer. For the first one keep in mind the popup blocker from browser is active by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your problem, You want to open pop up when **URL** containers #id like this
**exaple.com/#id**

You check if URL contains #id, then click anchor tag **Programmatically**

Comment: I think no, you have to open programmatically